# Schema with a min and max limit?

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

Is it possible to add a min and max limit to the following schema?

I would like schema to throw an exception when `Number` is < 0 and > 100.

```
(def Number
  schema/Int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `schema/pred` to incorporate arbitrary predicates:

```
(schema/pred #(<= 0 % 100))
```

You can also combine that with a schema using `schema/constrained`:

```
(schema/constrained schema/Int #(<= 0 % 100))
```

You get better error messages if you name your predicate (e. g. `in-range`).